# Pattern in java using numbers

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to print the following pattern but don't get the logic how to.. Can you please help me out.. I am using BlueJ and this is my first question so I am not sure what is required.

```
                1
               2 2
             3 3 3 3
           4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Thank You in advance.

i have tried this

```
public class Program92
{
    public static void main()
    {
        for(int x=1;x<=5;x++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=x;j++)
             System.out.print(x);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

but could only get

```
                1
                22
                333
                4444
                55555
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site for solving your homework INSTEAD of you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried in my notebook and absolutely can't get it....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because op's lack of effort to solve this.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera I'm sorry that i troubled you.

Comment: @Anirudh no need to say sorry. Just show your effort here... effort always appreciate here. Also when posting question without an effort will leads close your question without getting any help.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera i added my attempt to the post

Comment: I have a tip for you: The first line is special and doesn't follow the same rule as the other lines. So, print the first line and then use loops for the following lines.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck i know that it should print the line_number+1 numbers if you keep 1 out....

Comment: thank you all for the response, I got the pattern after straining my head for an hour.... Do you think it would be fine if I am printing 1 outside the loop?

Comment: hi all can you please look at my question on the same logic but now i need formatting help.. thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697251/formatting-concerning-patterns/28697623?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this snippet of code as it will print first blank space then your number. and also after every number there is blank space.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int l= 5;int k=0;
     for(int x=1;x<5;x++)
        {
         for(int i=l*2-1;i>0;i--)
         {  
            if(x == 1 && i ==1)
                break;
            System.out.print(" "); 
         }
         System.out.print(x); 
         System.out.print(" "); 
         for(int i=1;i<x*2-2;i++)
         {
             System.out.print(x); 
             System.out.print(" "); 
         }
         System.out.println();
         l--;
        }

        }
```

Comment: wait i need 1/22/3333/444444

Comment: @Anirudh : now check! condition was till 5, now it will print till 4.

Comment: @Anirudh whats the pattern?? 1,2,4,6 then??

Comment: it is in the question can't format properly in comment

Comment: @Anirudh : changed it test once

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I HAD GOTTEN THE LOGIC BUT NEEDED FORMATTING HELP!! THANKS ALOT! I POSTED IT HERE: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697251/formatting-concerning-patterns/28697623?)

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be homework, see if you can manage to get it to build a right angled triangle with those numbers, so `1` on top, 2 `2`'s beneath it, 4 `3`'s beneath that, etc:

```
1
2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Once that you manage that, *all* that you would need to do would be to figure out how many white space values you need to add before each number.

Comment: @Anirudh: Sorry my mistake, you would need to 4 `3`'s and 6 `4`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class program98
{
public static void main()
{
System.out.print("     "+"1");//5 spaces int the blank
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
 for(int s=6;s>1;s--)
   {System.out.print(" ");//1 space
    }
  for(int j=1;j<1;j++)
    {System,out.print(i);
     }
    for(int j=1;j<1;j++)
      {System.out.print(i);//prints this twice. Hence,instead of once,the number of times it prints is double
       }
         System.out.println(" ");//1 space
        }
       }
      }
```